# hide and show a javafx stage from an other class with keeping all the information

Tags: java, javafx

I have this JavaFx app when I press one of the buttons, an other javafx class lauch!

[image]

[image]
 so all what i need to know is : when I press the back button of the seconde class I need to find the first window with the same values entred in the bigging ! 
here what I can do for now:

```java
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            new MainApp().start(stage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            log.error(errors.toString());
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is the solution: 
let's suppose you have those 2 TextField one of them called apiurl and other called mainUrl ! all what you have to do is to to create `String url = "";` and go to your button action and add this line : `url=apiurl.getText();` in the **initialize method** in your controller add this : `apiurl.setText(url);` and this worked well for me !

Comment: @kleopatra no I tried this solution that you propose and it did not work

Comment: then you did something wrong - passing parameters around (with one of the various options mentioned in the referenced answer) does work _always_ As an aside: you seem to have a very effective crystal ball - this answer has no relation to the question and still is accepted ;) Aside: in case you are the same person as the OP with two accounts: the moment you start upvoting between those accounts you are violating the rules of the site and might get in trouble, just saying ..

Comment: @kleopatra in my case since my variable is needed to be used in other class I put it static but in her case truly she can delete the "static" key word! I updated the response

Comment: just stating the obvious - there is __no__ relation between the question and this answer ;) If you consider facts as rude I can't help it *shrugs